# ()Sign-alternating series of integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I need to calculate

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^1(-1)^n(\frac{1+t^2}{2})^ndt$$

(which is convergent because of sign-alternating absolute-value-tend-to-zero series)

I can put the $\sum$ into the integral if $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n(\frac{1+t^2}{2})^n$ converges uniformly in $[0,1]$, which is not true since if $t=1$ then the series does not converge. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

The series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n$$
converges uniformly on each compact $[0,1-\epsilon]$, $0<\epsilon<1$. So you just have to integrate on $[0,1-\epsilon]$ and then switch $\int$ and $\sum$:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{1-\epsilon}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2}\right)^ndt&=\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2}\right)^ndt\\
&=\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{2}{3+t^2}dt\\
& =\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \left(\frac{1-\epsilon}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
\\
& \longrightarrow\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}
\end{align}
$$ as $\epsilon$ tends to 0.

Comment: Then we must prove that limit of sum of integral is equal to sum of limit of integral, which I don't have any idea how to do.

Comment: @Mr.T The uniform convergence on $[0,1-\epsilon]$ allows you to switch the two operators.

Comment: You have calculated $\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\sum\int_0^{1-\varepsilon}$, but I don't see clearly why it is equal to $\sum\int_0^1$

Comment: @Mr.T Just because $$\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \left(\frac{1-\epsilon}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \longrightarrow \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$$

Comment: You seem to not understand what I'm confused. How $\sum_0^\infty\int_0^{1-\varepsilon}$ is a continuous function of $\varepsilon$? It's not clear to me :D

Comment: @Mr.T Simply put, you can use basic property of integration: $$\int (f(x)+g(x)+h(x)+\cdots)\,dx=\int f(x)\,dx+\int g(x)\,dx+\int h(x)\,dx+\cdots$$or vice versa

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am not satisfied with your argument. My confusion still remains. Hope you can explain it later or someone will :)

Comment: @Mr.T Please, do you know this theorem: 'A function given as a power series, can be integrated **termwise** on every compact set included in the domain of convergence.' Thanks.

Comment: yes, but $[0,1]$ is clearly not included in that compact set. You $\varepsilon$ argument is valid to me until you take the limit. :D